# Return type for an empty Promise.resole() new Promise Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm struggling with `return type` for the current function (example):

```
const someFunction = () => {
    if (condition) {
        return Promise.resolve()
    }
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
}
```

How do I define a `type` that this function returns?

I know that I can set `unknown` or `any`, but I'm looking for a cleaner approach.

Comment: `Promise<void>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Promise` as generic,

```
const someFunction = (): Promise<void> => {
    if (condition) {
        return Promise.resolve()
    }
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
}
```

*instead of `void` you can use another type, based on your Promise resolve*

Comment: @ Alexander T. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I think, `Promise<any>` is a good solution here.
Since, we haven't defined `return` type from `resolve` methods.